# File generated using jaxb is not complete (missing end tags, etc)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

We use jaxb with spring oxm to generate large xml files for transactions processing in multiple threads. All working fine. We got an wired issues that one of the generated xml is corrupted with tags are not closed properly. We generate all the files in Mount drive of solaris(NFS). We didn't get any errors in server log also. We don't have any clue to start investigations.

If anyone encountered same issue or know anything please help us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually the case of an FileOutputStream or FileWriter being used and not flushed/closed properly after the marshal.